# How to test broadcast driver?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am wondering if its possible to test `ShouldBroadcast` in Laravel?
My test will trigger the even that implements `ShouldBroadcast`, however, I've noticed that broadcasting didn't happen.

Of course, the broadcasting event is working in the app it self.

Has any one tried such test?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's an old question, but just in case it can help someone : i did for myself an assert function that you should add to your TestCase.php.

The idea is to set the broadcast driver to "log" and then to read the 4th line from the end to see if it's a broadcast log.

**In your phpunit.xml**

Add the folowing line to the  node:

```
<env name="BROADCAST_DRIVER" value="log"/>
```

**In your TestCase.php file**

Add the folowing function :

```
public function assertEventIsBroadcasted($eventClassName, $channel=""){
  $logfileFullpath = storage_path("logs/laravel.log");
  $logfile = explode("\n", file_get_contents($logfileFullpath));

  if(count($logfile) > 4){
    $supposedLastEventLogged = $logfile[count($logfile)-5];

    $this->assertContains("Broadcasting [", $supposedLastEventLogged, "No broadcast were found.\n");

    $this->assertContains("Broadcasting [".$eventClassName."]", $supposedLastEventLogged, "A broadcast was found, but not for the classname '".$eventClassName."'.\n");

    if($channel != "")
      $this->assertContains("Broadcasting [".$eventClassName."] on channels [".$channel."]", $supposedLastEventLogged, "The expected broadcast (".$eventClassName.") event was found, but not on the expected channel '".$channel."'.\n");
  }else{
    $this->fail("No informations found in the file log '".$logfileFullpath."'.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking what's written in log, you can to use the assertion 'expectsEvents', which you can test if a certain event is launched.

```
public function testMethod(){
   $this->expectsEvents(YourEventClass::class)
    ...your code test...
}
```

For more info:
 https://laravel-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mocking/

Answer (score 1):

with Adrienc solutions with dynamically getting index of last event

```
private function getIndexOfLoggedEvent(array $logfile)
{
    for ($i = count($logfile) - 1; $i >=0 ; $i--) {
        if (strpos($logfile[$i], 'Broadcasting [Illuminate\Notifications\Events\BroadcastNotificationCreated]') !== false) {
            return $i;
        }
    }
}
```

which will give you index of the line of last broadcast

Comment: Your basically just testing your logs, not broadcasting.

Answer (score 0):

I took both previous answers, and put them together.

This works with laravel 5.7.

In your **TestCase.php** file:

```
public function assertEventIsBroadcasted($eventClassName, $channel = '')
{
    $date = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
    $logfileFullpath = storage_path("logs/laravel-{$date}.log");
    $logfile = explode("\n", file_get_contents($logfileFullpath));
    $indexOfLoggedEvent = $this->getIndexOfLoggedEvent($logfile);

    if ($indexOfLoggedEvent) {
        $supposedLastEventLogged = $logfile[$indexOfLoggedEvent];
        $this->assertContains('Broadcasting [', $supposedLastEventLogged, "No broadcast were found.\n");

        $this->assertContains(
            'Broadcasting [' . $eventClassName . ']',
            $supposedLastEventLogged,
            "A broadcast was found, but not for the classname '" . $eventClassName . "'.\n"
        );

        if ($channel != '') {
            $this->assertContains(
                'Broadcasting [' . $eventClassName . '] on channels [' . $channel . ']',
                $supposedLastEventLogged,
                'The expected broadcast (' . $eventClassName . ") event was found, but not on the expected channel '" . $channel . "'.\n"
            );
        }
    } else {
        $this->fail("No informations found in the file log '" . $logfileFullpath . "'.");
    }
}

private function getIndexOfLoggedEvent(array $logfile)
{
    for ($i = count($logfile) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        if (strpos($logfile[$i], 'local.INFO: Broadcasting') !== false) {
            return $i;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

A test could look like this:

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function notifications_are_broadcasted()
{
    $notification = factory(Notification::class)->create();
    broadcast(new NewNotification($notification));
    $this->assertEventIsBroadcasted(
        NewNotificationEvent::class,
        'private-notification.' . $notification->id
    );
}
```